# Blazor framework JavaScript removes events from page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blazor, asp.net-blazor

We are building a new website and have a problem with blazor and javascript. We have a file called `page.js` (from a template) that contains all the javascript we need. There are some events that are set by this file.

For example,

```
$canvas.on('mousemove', function(e){
        config.position.x = e.pageX - $canvas.offset().left;
        config.position.y = e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top;
});
```

binds to a canvas with dots that should follow the users mouse ([Constellation Plugin](https://gist.github.com/E-Bo/ce28240b0bdb23918bbc)). This mousemove event is gone as soon as the `_framework.blazor.js` script loads. Other events such as `click`, `focus` and `blur` also disappear on other elements.

All these events are gone after loading the blazor `_framework.blazor.js`. I added a delay to the loading of the blazor framework to check that the events were present / initialized correctly. Exactly after the delay time the events disappeared.

The script tag for `page.js` is in `_Host.cshtml` and loaded before the blazor framework JavaScript file.

When setting the server mode to `Static` the site works as expected (because the blazor JavaScript file is not used).

Is this intended behavior of Blazor? I know you can use JavaScript functions though JSInterop,but I need to load the file as if it was in a script tag.

Comment: Are you sure the events are gone, and not that they're attaching to DOM components that aren't there at the time it runs?

Comment: You need to describe what events you are binding to (and how) in `page.js`.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I added the info to the post, but in short: the events are visible for a period of time before disappearing.

Comment: @KirkWoll thank you for the suggestion, I added an example and info the post.

Comment: Where do you call your JS function? While a Blazor app is prerendering, certain actions, such as calling into JavaScript (JS interop), aren't possible. Components may need to render differently when prerendered.

Comment: This is still an issue in december 2022